# How to use Session object in value attribute of `html` input field on jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using rollno as session object and i have to use that value in the value attribute of "html" input field here is my `jsp` coding

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
     <%@page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"%> 
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
     <%!HttpSession value=null; %>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form action="ShowMarkServlet">
     <% value=(HttpSession)session.getAttribute("rollno");%>
     <%out.print(session.getAttribute("rollno")); %>
     Rollnumber:<input type="number" value="<%=value%>" name="rollno"><br>
     Enter the semester:<input type="number" name="semester" min="0" max="6">
     <input type="submit" value="okay">
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Here is my `servlet` coding the rollno  has value in this servlet but shows null in the jsp file.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      String rollno=request.getParameter("rollnumber");
      System.out.println(rollno);
      String report=request.getParameter("domainarea");
      System.out.println(report);
      HttpSession session=request.getSession();
      session.setAttribute(rollno,"rollno");
      if(report.equals("MarkDetail")){
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/sem.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what are you going to do with it, understand that those htmls are formed by servlet in which jsp transforms after compilation

Comment: okay but how to access that session object ,it shows null in the jsp display              `<%out.print(session.getAttribute("rollno")); %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can access session from jsp just by `session`, so your code should look like:

```
<% String value=session.getAttribute("rollno");%>
<% out.print(value); %>
```

Or using [EL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm):

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="ShowMarkServlet">
 Rollnumber:<input type="number" value="${rollno}" name="rollno"><br>
 Enter the semester:<input type="number" name="semester" min="0" max="6">
 <input type="submit" value="okay">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

If i got your intensions right

Comment: Session is just there, holding values you've written in there, you should not getting it anyway harder than using `session` in jsp, and in EL all variables are looked through request and session so you should not even bother about where they are

Comment: My intention is same but its too not working ${rollno}`session.setAttribute(String arg,"obj")` we can not save an object in a String
<% String value=session.getAttribute("rollno");%>`

Comment: I just wrote string following your example, any object can be stored in session, and then you should access it as object, for example you do: `request.getSession().setAttribute("rollno", a)` in your servlet where a is an object of A, then inside jsp you should do `A a = (A)session.getAttribute("rollno")` and the you can use it as A object, accessing it's fields and methods